# Install GDAL Library in Docker Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gdal, osgeo

I'm trying to install GDAL in a docker container running the CVAT tool. The base docker file can be found here https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/cvat/blob/develop/Dockerfile . I modified it to add GDAL using several recommended ways but always seems to run into errors.

This is the current modification I made in the dockerfile for GDAL which still fails.

```
# Install GDAL
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common && apt-get update
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa &&  apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gdal-bin libgdal-dev libpq-dev
ARG CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
ARG C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
RUN pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal" GDAL==`gdal-config --version`
```

I also tried adding a specific version of GDAL in the requirements file (https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/cvat/blob/develop/cvat/requirements/base.txt) but it still fails while building GDAL.

How do I install GDAL so that I can run some CRS conversions inside the docker container?

Update: For now just CRS conversions but in the future I need to handle some raster tasks as well so I would prefer to import the full GDAL module.

Comment: You can install it from [ubuntugis](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGIS) - but maybe you can get away with using only `pyproj` instead of the full GDAL if you only need to do CRS conversions

Comment: @Val I need to use gdal, ogr and osr modules. For now just conversions but I would need them in future for other raster tasks so I would like to import the full module.

Comment: ubuntugis is the way to go then!